# Rails multipole sites using the same database / shared tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am currently looking at using rails for a web app im working on..

It's a contact database for my church, with some fairly complex user authorization stuff (V Sensitive data)

I'm also looking at building a fairly complex (Content Deep) site for them using rails too..

What i'd really like to do is have it so the user can have the same login etc.. for the contact database, the blog, the download site etc..

i havent really used rails much but is it possible to have multiple apps running on the same database?

and if so is it possible to have your user model in one application have more fields than in another (reading from the same table)..

i.e.

User in the contact database would have fields like, name, age, can_see_x etc..
Where a User in the blog wouldnt have the can_see_x field..

could these models be reading from the same table?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those are possible. You just have to make sure the data in the db config file is the same.

As far as making one user model have more fields than another, you can use the `attr_accessible` tag to determine which fields are accessible in each respective model.

For example: One user model could look like this

`attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :total_sales`

While another would look like this:

`attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :birthday`

In the first, you'd be able to access `user_object.total_sales`, but not `user_object.birthday`. The reverse is also true.